# Unable to click button using pywinauto on a specific window on Windows 8 or 10

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am performing automation testing of an application using `pywinauto`.

It worked successfully for every window of the app, but for some reason it fails to click the buttons on the install wizard, on Windows 8 and Windows 10. **It works on Windows 7.**

Tested with

- python 2.7.10.amd64
- pywinauto 0.5.3
- Windows 10 x64

I can get the button coordinates, text, and every other info, however I cannot perform any action on it (click, press key)

The error I get is:

```
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\HwndWrapper.py", line 900, in ClickInput self, button, coords, double, wheel_dist = wheel_dist, use_log = use_log, pressed = pressed, absolute = absolute)  
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\HwndWrapper.py", line 1778, in _perform_click_input  win32api.SetCursorPos((coords[0], coords[1])) pwintypes.error: (0, 'SetCursorPos', 'No error message is available')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it UAC confirmation window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to click on UAC confirmation window. You can do nothing with it from any script at all. Please disable UAC (to zero level) on your Win8/Win10 machines. This is the only way for install/uninstall GUI automation.

Python process must run as administrator of course.

BTW, some installers allow silent modes (`msiexec.exe /i [MSI_path]` or `setup.exe /S` for NullSoft (NSIS) installers). Of course it's not the case if you're testing an installer GUI itself.

Comment: Hi Vasily, I am testing with the UAC window disabled.

Comment: Is Python running as administrator as well?

Comment: It was not. I managed to run it as administrator, however another problem appeared. It starts two install wizards. I will need to investigate this. The bigger problem is fixed now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: OK, reflected it in the answer. The case might be useful to others so upvoting it.